# using you youtube api on node.js

Tags: node.js, google-api, youtube-api

I could someone give me an example of how to login to the google api using oauth and use the livestream.update command on node.js. Sorry if this is noob question

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

https://scotch.io/tutorials/easy-node-authentication-google

Or this one:

https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/

Or this one:

https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-google-oauth

I hope help you with the examples.